# LocationClient requestLocationUpdate does not accept "this" as a valid parameter

Tags: android, location-client

My MainActivity implements  GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener but when I call `mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationUpdates, this)`
(mLocationClient is a global variable of LocationClient) I get an error stating that "Cant resolve method requestLocationUpdate(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest, com.example.mainActivity).

Is my class missing something? Following the google tutorial and other examples, this method works. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please post your Activity code so we can see what is going on. As per the answer it should be working if you implemented the LocationListener interface.

Answer (score 1):

your Activity must implements `LocationListener`

[LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html)

Please Mark as Asnwer if it Helped you.

Comment: I have implemented LocationListener in my Activity and all the methods that need to be overwritten. But still to no avail. Had I implemented it, shouldnt "this" then work as one of the parameters of requestLocationUpdate(LocationRequest, LocationListener)?
@WillieNel

Comment: if you did public MainAcitivity extends Activity implements LocationListener then "this" should works.